# Tossing a fair coin until two consecutive heads

Tags: probability

Let's say you toss a single coin until you get two consecutive heads. For a given integer k, k>=2, what is the probability that the last head will appear on the k:th throw?
Getting two or more tails in a row is of no interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $p(1)=0$ and $p(2)=\frac{1}{4}.$
For $k\ge 3$, the first throws must either be

T with two heads then occurring on the $k-1$th throw after this

HT with two heads then occurring on the $k-2$th throw after this.

You can therefore calculate further probabilities using the recurrence relation $p(k+2)=\frac{1}{2}p(k+1)+\frac{1}{4}p(k)$.

An explicit formula is $$p(n)=\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}\sqrt 5}((1+\sqrt 5)^{n-1}-(1-\sqrt 5)^{n-1}).$$

Comment: Thank you! I am curious though if you could explain how you set up the recurrence relation a bit further? My knowledge of probability is quite basic, and I'm having trouble getting an intuitive understanding of how and why this actually works.

Comment: The general idea with many problems of this type is to look at possibilities for initial turns.

Comment: For example the first throw is T with probability $1/2$. Then two heads will occur after a total of $k$ turns if they occur after a further $k-1$ turns. This eventuality therefore has probability $\frac{1}{2}p(k-1)$.